# java test failure on a specific agent

Tags: maven, jenkins, build

I am encountering an issue with a Maven build job on Jenkins -
when it runs on "agent2" it succeeds!

when the same job runs on "agent2" it fails a specific test every time...

the code is the same in both runs.
we use Maven Integration plugin.
artifact resolve from artifactory.

edit with more info:
java 1.8, a junit test that uses assert - on one agent gets an expected value - while on the other not. there are no clear-to-the-eye differences between the agents - trying to find out what this difference may be. the code is pulled from bitbucket and then built with maven(clean install)

any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you give more details cause I don't know a Maven Integration plugin? What kind of test do you run? What is the difference between the nodes? How are you calling Maven and the tests? which Java versions? Which Jenkins version? etc. ?

Comment: java 1.8, a junit test that uses assert - on one slave gets an expected value - while on the other not. 
there are no clear-to-the-eye differences between the slaves - trying to find out what this difference may be.
the code is pulled from bitbucket and then built with maven(clean install).

Comment: Sorry but this does not help..Show the code of the test and explain what the test is really testing? Also the other information I've mentioned...